# Inverse of sparse matrix is not generally sparse

Tags: matrix-theory, sparse-matrices

I have a question regarding inverse of square sparse matrices(or can be restricted to real symmetric positive definite matrices).

I encountered several times the web pages which states that the inverse of the sparse matrix is not usually sparse and my experience also said so. One exception can be diagonal matrices.

How theses kind of assertions can be verified?

EDIT: As suggested by Yemon Choi, it would be better to ask if there is a precise way to say that the inverses of "most" sparse matrices are not sparse.

NOTE : This was asked in math stack exchange earlier, but no one seems to answer it so I posted here too. Looking forward to great answers.:)

Comment: You can verify these assertions by looking at examples, surely. Try a tridiagonal matrix whose non-zero entries are all 1. This question seems too basic for MathOverflow

Comment: @YemonChoi: Yes your example can be an example. However, I am not sure how this answers my question. I can think of another example such as matrices with translation symmetry since their discrete Fourier components are all non-zero, which makes their inverse is not sparse. But they are just examples.

Comment: @YemonChoi: As I wrote in the text, my experience also says so. However What I am asking is why inverse of majority of sparse matrices is not sparse. I don't think it is too trivial.

Comment: OK, now I understand your question, I think you should edit the original post to make it more clear that you are asking if there is a **precise** way to say that the inverses of "most" sparse matrices are not sparse

Comment: @YemonChoi: Sorry for my bad English. Maybe I wanted to find something statistical proof of the assertion. I will edit the question according to your wording.

Comment: I deleted some more precise comments because I think I found an error in one of my bounds, so I'll just make a more general statement. The answer to this question will, of course, depend on model of a sparse matrix you are using. The simplest model (Erdos-Renyi) is that you have an $n \times n$ matrix with $N$ nonzero entries. The positions of those entries in the matrix are chosen uniformly at random, and those $N$ matrix entries are real numbers with no algebraic relations between them.

Comment: If $N$, as a function of $n$, grows slower than $n \log n - c n$ for any $c$, then the matrix has a zero row with probability $1$ -- see Erdos and Renyi "On Random matrices" -- and is hence not invertible. If $N$ is larger than this, then the matrix is invertible with positive probability and we may as well reorder the rows such that the diagonal entries are all nonzero.

Comment: We then have the easy lemma: Let $A$ be a matrix with nonzero diagonal entries, and no algebraic relations between nonzero entries. Let $G$ be a directed graph where there is an edge $i \to j$ if $A_{ij} \neq 0$. Then $(A^{-1})_{ij}$ is nonzero if and only if there is a path $i \to \to \to \cdots \to j$ in $G$. I'd start searching on various subsets of the terms "random graph" "directed graph" "digraph" "Erdos Renyi" "strongly connected components" "transitive closure". As yet, I haven't found a paper addressing this question with those keywords, but it should be out there.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Thank you for your time and effort. That is what I was looking for. The logic seems fine. I will also search those papers with the keywords. Please leave a comment if you find a good reference.

Comment: The m.se post was http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471136/inverse-of-sparse-matrix-is-not-generally-sparse --- OP waited all of 4 hours before deciding no one was answering it.